# Does asp:ImageButton have property to store misc string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does `asp:ImageButton` have property to store string?

Is would be something similar to the Windows Button `Tag` property.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @tnw, I read the documentation, but couldn't find it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.alternatetext(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: @rbhatup Where do you plan to retrieve that string back? Could you not use HiddenField?

Comment: I can use HiddenField, ViewState, Session, and a bunch of other options.

Comment: I simply wanted to know if asp:ImageButton had a Tag property, and someone just downvoted it for no reason at all.

Comment: @rbhatup I mean it's pretty straight forward. You said you read the documentation. It doesn't have a `Tag` property. Also, downvotes on a question indicate that it is unclear or not useful. Perhaps it was downvoted because it's a matter of reading the documentation and is therefore not useful.

Comment: I asked if the Button control had something to store a string, _similar_ to the Tag property. I never asked if it had a Tag property.

Comment: @rbhatup Verbatim your comment: "I simply wanted to know if asp:ImageButton had a Tag property".

Comment: @rbhatup What on earth are you talking about? You can't downvote a comment. I don't need to be a mind reader to downvote a question. I vote on the question, not what's on your mind. Your question was already not clear/not useful (therefore downvoted). Your comments haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own `attributes` to any control and read them later if needed.

```
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("tag", myVar);
```

And then read it somewhere later.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myVar = ImageButton1.Attributes["tag"];
}
```